# How to train encoder in BiGAN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, autoencoder, gan

I have some difficulties training a BiGAN. In particular, the encoder seems not learning the map between the images **x** and the latent space **z**.

I have the following encoder:

```
def build_encoder(self):
        model = Sequential(name = "Encoder")

        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides = (2, 2), activation = "relu", input_shape = self.image_shape, padding = "same"))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (5, 5), strides = (2, 2), activation = "relu", input_shape = self.image_shape, padding = "same"))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(self.noise_dim))

        return model
```

And the following encoder loss:

```
def encoder_loss(self, real_output, real_images, fake_images):
        real_loss = self.cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(real_output), real_output)
        residual_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(real_images - fake_images))
        total_loss = real_loss + residual_loss
        return total_loss
```

Where the *real output* is the discriminator output given real images.

The training seems to go pretty well, since the generated images from random latent vectors are good. So the generator learns the map from **z** to **x**, but if i try to encode an image and decode it with the generator model, the result will be a complete different picture.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

After some work I haven't come up with a real solution. I assume that this is not a good loss to train the encoder. I got better results whit this one:

```
def encoder_loss(self, image, reconstructed_image):
        return self.mse(image, reconstructed_image)
```

Where the image(s) will be encoded and then decoded (like an autoencoder).

Another way is calculate the loss on the latent vectors:

```
def encoder_loss(self, random_noise, encoded_image):
        return self.mse(random_noise, encoded_image)
```

On my tests this one works but is not as good as the first one.